# C++ template for class children possible?

Tags: c++, class, templates

I have a parent class "ICtl" which is an interface with pure virtual methods and I have multiple children classes that derive from it (let's say CButton : public ICtl, CPanel : public ICtl, etc.)

For example there's a common generic method SetPos(int& x, int& y) that, however would have different implementations for each class.

Is it possible to write template that would be child-class agnostic and simply call that method?

Like for example (obviously this code is wrong and will not work):

```
template<ICtl* P>
void(P pCtl, int x, int y)
{
   pCtl->SetPos(x,y);
}
```

but done in a correct way?

Comment: why wouldn't it be in the common parent then?

Comment: Your function can just take a reference or a pointer to the parent. For example `void myFunc(ICtl& ctl) { ctl.SetPos(0,0); }`. You can just pass in the children

Answer (score 3):

You need no template. If `ICtl` has a virtual method called `SetPos` you can pass instances of derived classes via reference to the base:

```
void set(ICtl& pCtl, int x, int y)
{
   pCtl.SetPos(x,y);
}
```

However, it is unclear what purpose this method serves, because now the caller has to call `set(pctl,x,y)` when they can simply call `pctl.SetPos(x,y)` directly.

Roughly speaking, you would need a template if you wanted to call a method called `SetPos` on instances of otherwise completely unrelated types. When the instances share a common base that offers the interface you want to use, there is no need for a template.